# how to run another JavaScript function when sweet alert script is running

Tags: javascript

I want to implement javascript function to delete confirmation. After clicking `ok` button of confirmation alert table `tr` should be removed from front end. I have used `$("#confirm-btn-alert").click(function()` for confirmation alert which is in `sweet-alert-script.js` and `function SomeDeleteRowFunction(o)` which is in `newfile.html` for remove `tr`

sweet-alert-script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#confirm-btn-alert").click(function(){

        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                    icon: "success",
                });
            } else {
                swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

newfile.html

```
<script>
    function SomeDeleteRowFunction(o) {
        var p=o.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You have stated what you are trying to achieve. Now we need to know, what error or problem you are facing.

Comment: @Marco i  am not getting a error... but i want to know how can i connect thsese two functions to delete the row when clicking `ok` button of confirmation message.

Comment: Probably nothing to do with your specific issue, but your closing `script` tag is missing a `>` sign

Comment: @M̨̹̖̱̠̭̠̱̘͌̓ͬͫa̧͔͇̗͖͖͑ͭ͝t̆͗̊ͫt It is copy paste mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just enough to find that `table` and `tr` in confirmation of `alert` based on information [here](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#installation), if the user clicks the confirm button, the promise resolves to `true`. If the alert is dismissed (by clicking outside of it), the promise resolves to `null`, so if `willDelete` be true in `if (willDelete)` condition it means user confirm it and you can delete what you want.

I provide two sample working code snipped to help as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    function SomeDeleteRowFunction(table,child) { 
        table.find(child).remove();
        // you can also play with table and child (child is tr)
    }
    $(".delete").click(function(){ 
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                var $tbl = $(this).closest('table');
                var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); 
                SomeDeleteRowFunction($tbl,$tr);
                swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                    icon: "success",
                });
            } else {
                swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
            }
        });

    });
   $("#confirm-btn-alert").click(function(){ 
        swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                var $tbl = $('#tbl2');
                var $tr = $('#tr1'); 
                SomeDeleteRowFunction($tbl,$tr);
                swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                    icon: "success",
                });
            } else {
                swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
            }
        });

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://sweetalert.js.org/assets/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first td</td> 
    <td>second td</td>
    <td>TR1 content <button class="delete">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TR2 content<button class="delete">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>TR3 content<button class="delete">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<table id="tbl2">
  <tr id="tr1">
    <td>Table 2 TR1 content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr2">
    <td>Table 2 TR2 content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tr3">
    <td>Table 2 TR3 content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="confirm-btn-alert">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great response... But when i add several `<td>`s to table  then they are not deleted....` <tr> <td>first td</td><td>second td</td>
    <td>TR1 content <button class="delete">Remove</button></td>
  </tr>`

Comment: because `$(this).parent()` get the `td` which is parent of clicked button there are some ways to get `tr`, use `$(this).closest('tr')` or `$(this).parent().parent()` or  etc, see the update.

Comment: please don't use this answer for tests purpose, copy the code in your local compute or use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), anyway if the answer helps you please accept it as answer by the check mark icon in top left of answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the same method you used to click the confirm button !
Change the `<script> function` with the below content

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ok-button-id").click(function(o){
        var p=o.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
    })
});
```

Or if the `<tr>` has an ID, it's so easy for you.
`<tr id="myTableRow"><td>Confirmation message here</td></tr>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ok-button-id").click(function(){
         $('#myTableRow').remove();
    })
});
```

Here is another way

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTableID tr').click(function(){ //Here 'this' will be the table row
        $(this).remove();
        return false;
    })
});
```